# Freeswitch handle pstn calls for switched off numbers

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

In freeswitch when i try to call **PSTN** number which is switched off, It will keep sending **INVITE** message.

How to handle **PSTN** call for switched off numbers in freeswitch?

Answer (score 1):

Your trunk carrier should send `480 Temporarily Unavailable` on switched off numbers.

If you're not getting then you need to use `bridge_answer_timeout` on PSTN calls before bridge application to make sure you end the call in certain duration. This prevents re-invite

Answer (score 0):

looks like your ITSP is not returning the correct status, so it's nothing to do with your FreeSWITCH server